# Outer measure regularity property proof and example

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

Can someone prove me the following measure theory Lesbegue outer measure property. I have been looking for its proof and intuition but I have not found it yet. **$\forall E \in\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R}), \epsilon > 0, \exists O\:\:\:\text{open set in}\:\mathbb{R}:O\supset E\:\:\:\text{and}\:\mu^*_l(E)\leqslant\mu^*_l(O)\leqslant\mu^*_l(E)+\epsilon$**

This property implies that $\mu^*_l(E)=\mu^*_l(O)$ but how? If $O\supset E$. Is this just a property to help prove equalities? Which are the examples of this on the real line? 
I am asking this because this property has been used to solve the following problem whose statement seems to be paradoxical, I guess.

**Prove that for every $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ , there exists a there exists a $G\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that:
$G\supset E$ and $\mu^*_l(E)=\mu^*_l(G)$**
[image]

How can $G\supset E$ and $\mu^*_l(E)=\mu^*_l(G)$? It seems a contradiction.

Comment: Your statement "This property implies that $\mu_l^*(E)=\mu_l^*(O)$ but how?" doesn't make sense.Of course it doesn't.

Comment: Yes you are right. But if you refer to the example I provided from a book, for me it does not make a lot of sense either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property says that

> Every subset of the real line can be arbitrarily approximated by an open subset from above,

i.e. for every $E\subseteq\Bbb R$ and $\varepsilon>0$ there is an open $O\supseteq E$ with $\mu^*(O)\le\mu^*(E)+\varepsilon$.

And it *doesn't follow* anything more than that, in particular, we don't necessarily have an *open* set $O$ with $\mu^*(E)=\mu^*(O)$.

But, we can always intersect (countably) infinitely many of them to get a **$G_\delta$-set** $G$ which already satisfies the sharper $\mu^*(E)=\mu^*(G)$, using the above approximations for $\varepsilon=1/n$ values.

For a lightweight illustration, take $E$ to be a cheese with tiny-tiny holes (or more mathematically, e.g. $E:=(0,1)\setminus\Bbb Q$) and just fill those holes (taking $O:=(0,1)$).

Finally, even in this example we have infinitely many points in $O\setminus E$, but still $\mu^*(E)=\mu^*(O)$.

Comment: In your example $E:=(0,1)\setminus\Bbb)$and just fill those holes (taking  $Q O:=(0,1)$) You are implying that the cardinality of the set is higher hence $O\supset G$ but the length given by the outer measure is the same. Could you expand your answer on the  $G_\delta$? It

Comment: it stills seems paradoxical to me that exercise unless every case is as you said, about cardinality of  the set. Could you please show me a link to those proofs. I am studying Introduction to Measure and Integration by Taylor, is there any proof of that kind on this book? Thanks!

Comment: To the OP; Most cases are not about the cardinality,...$(0,1)$ \ $\mathbb Q$ is a simple example.  Two sets $A,B$ may have equal outer measure, or equal inner measure, or equal measure, even though one of them is a proper subset of the other.  Measure is an extension of the idea of length, The length of $(0,1)$ and of $[0,1]$ are the same, even though one of them is a proper subset of the other.